# PHP Micorosoft Access get data using ADODB

Tags: php, ms-access

I'm working with PHP and Microsoft Access database (.mdb).

Until this below code I'm sure this is connected to the .mdb file database.

```
$db = realpath("att2000.mdb") or die('<b>Connectie met database mislukt</b>');

$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection");
$conn->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$db");

$a = $conn->Execute("SELECT * FROM USERINFO");
\\I need to do while loop on this query data.
```

Now actually I don't know how to get the data on loop like doing `while`.

Inside the table `USERINFO` have column `USERID`.

So my question, how to show the data on loop using my above code?

Comment: new PDO ("odbc: Driver = {Microsoft Access Driver (* .mdb)};... is not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//your open ..
$sql = "SELECT * FROM USERINFO";
$rs = $conn->Execute($sql);

while (!$rs->EOF) {
  foreach($rs->Fields as $field){
    echo "Fieldname: ".$field->name." Value: ".$field->value."<br>\n";
  }
  echo "____<br>";
  $rs->MoveNext();
}

$rs->Close();
$conn->Close();
```